# unable to install testng plugin for eclipse kepler

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, testng

I am unable to install testng plugin for eclipse kepler.

I have followed this 
[document](http://howtodoinjava.com/2014/11/19/testng-tutorial-with-eclipse/) but I can't install the plugin.

When I try to enter the [URL](http://beust.com/eclipse)
  its shows getting child fetching children of the "name of the Repository"355 and then gives error provisioning exception:

> error essage-->No repository found at http download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.3.

How do I resolve this?

Comment: change the path of repository..

Comment: what ever i try to install from Windows->preferences->install new software  or form eclipse market place its saying                                                     No repository found at http://update.zeroturnaround.com/update-site.please help me ..